# Aggregate similar subsequent strings in a list in R

Tags: r, list, aggregate

My data is a very simple list called "customers" and has 300 customers' activities.

So, when I print(customers), I get [[1]] "StartPage", "ClickItem1", "ClickItem1", "ClickItem1", "ScrollItem1" etc, [[2]] "StartPage", "ClickItem1", "ScrollItem1", ClickItem2", "ScrollItem1",..., [[300]] "StartPage", "ClickItem4", "ScrollItem4", ClickItem2", "ScrollItem2".

**How can I aggregate similar subsequent activities?**

For example, the first customer should look like this [[1]] "StartPage", "ClickItem1", "ScrollItem1," etc.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

As there is no replication data, created list based on numbers.
You can use map function from tidyverse to loop through list.
To obtain non repetitive or unique names use unique function

```
library(tidyverse)
l<-list(rep(1:5,3),rep(2:6,2),3:7)
map(l,unique)
```